# Scraping multiple webpages and writing to a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm writing a program that will take seven pieces of data from a website and write it to a csv file per a company in the symbols.txt file, such as AAPL or NFLX. My problems seems to come from my confusion with index to make the script work. I am at a loss on how it fits. I thought that this format would work...

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import re
import urllib
# import modules

symbolfile = open("symbols.txt")
symbolslist = symbolfile.read()
newsymbolslist = symbolslist.split("\n")

i = 0

f = csv.writer(open("pe_ratio.csv","wb"))
# short cut to write

f.writerow(["Name","PE","Revenue % Quarterly","ROA% YOY","Operating Cashflow","Debt to Equity"])
#first write row statement

# define name_company as the following
while i<len(newsymbolslist):
    page = urllib2.urlopen("http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s="+newsymbolslist[i] +"%20Key%20Statistics").read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    name_company = soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "title"}) 
    for name in name_company: #add multiple iterations?     
        all_data = soup.findAll('td', "yfnc_tabledata1")
        stock_name = name.find('h2').string #find company's name in name_company with h2 tag
        f.writerow([stock_name, all_data[2].getText(),all_data[17].getText(),all_data[13].getText(), all_data[29].getText(),all_data[26].getText()]) #write down PE data
    i+=1
```

I get the following error below when I try to run the code as is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "company_data_v1.py", line 28, in <module>
    f.writerow([stock_name, all_data[2].getText(),all_data[17].getText(),all_data[13].getText(), all_data[29].getText()
all_data[26].getText()]) #write down PE data
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: It's spelled *scraping*, not scapping.  (Look right there in the tag).

Comment: What and where is `company_data_v1.py`? That's the file where the error is, why aren't you showing us that code?

Comment: company_data_v1.py is the name of the code that I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
name_company = soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "title"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(page) #this is the first time you define soup
```

You define `soup` on the line *after* you attempt to do `soup.findAll`.  Python tells you exactly what the problem is: you haven't defined `soup` at the `findAll` line.

Flip the order of those lines.

Comment: I did that. I am going to post the revised code up now with the new error message.

Comment: @RobertBirch these are very rudimentary problems you're having, I suggest spending time reading the errors and trying to understand what they're saying. We can't piecemeal debug *every* line of code you write.

Comment: Right. You've completely changed the code which changes the whole question. You need to learn to debug code on your own.

Comment: @Johnathon Reinhart I seriously think I should ban myself from stackoverflow just to learn to debug it. I will do that.

Comment: The code works now as is posted, but I am going to work out the bugs by myself.

Answer (score 1):

I assume when you said "where to put the variables to make the script work" you were referring to this 'soup' variable? The one in your error message?

If so then I suggest declaring 'soup' *before* you try to use it in soup.findAll(). As you can see, you declared soup = BeautifulSoup(page) one line *after* soup.findAll(). It should go above it.